# flutter - drag and drop - onAccept not called, because of state refresh

Tags: flutter, draggable

I have a widget that is refreshed every second, it is a set of 5 cells.
I wish to drag & drop each cell to each other.

So, I use a Draggable and a DragTarget.

Without the data refresh every second (because of the "setState" call) it workds fine.
When I activate the data refresh, it does not works, and I suppose it is because the widget is unmounted.

So, the "onAccept" is never called, and the drag's feedback remain suspended over all the other widgets.

Here is the code of the cell:

class ReorderableColumnCell extends StatelessWidget {
final dynamic data;
final Widget child;
final Function(dynamic source, dynamic target) onColumnDrag;

ReorderableColumnCell(this.data, this.child, this.onColumnDrag);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var dt = DragTarget(
builder: (
BuildContext context,
List accepted,
List rejected,
) {
return child;
},
onAccept: (dynamic data) {
onColumnDrag(data, this.data);
},
);

```
dynamic d = Draggable<ExtDataColumn>(
  data: data,
  feedback: Container(
    child: child,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
  ),
  childWhenDragging: child,
  child: dt,
);

return d;
```

}
}

The problem is that during the "drag", the "child" widget is unmounted (because of the state refresh).
But so, I have no idea about how I can fix this?